# Flow of execution when using ForEach in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a strange problem with flow of execution on a cluster.

Method A calls 
    - Method B which in a FOREACH calls 
        - Method C

The flow of execution should be

```
Method A --> Method B --> Method C
```

but it works as like this:

```
1) Method A --> Method B (skips Method C) and continues to rest of Method B.
2) Method C is executed later separately.
```

Because the flow isnt in correct flow, `accum1.value` in Method B is shown as `blank/null`.

```
**CLASS A::METHOD A:**

object TakeDFs {

    def takeDFs(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
        println("---------------- takeNettedDFs::START ---------------- ")

        for(i <- 0 until bySecurityArray.length) {
            allocProcessDF = bySecurityArray(i).toDF()
            ....

            //WORKS
            AllocOneProcess.getAllocOneDFs(allocProcessDF)

            }
        println("---------------- takeNettedDFs::END ---------------- ")

    }
}

**CLASS B::METHOD B:**

object AllocOneProcess {

    def getAllocOneDFs(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
        println("---------------- getAllocOneDFs::START ---------------- ")

        df.coalesce(1).sort($"PRIORITY" asc).foreach( {
        row => AllocOneTest.allocProcessTest(row)
        })

        println("------------- getAllocOneDFs::accum1.value -------------" + accum1.value)

        println("---------------- getAllocOneDFs::END ---------------- ")

    }
}

**CLASS C::METHOD C:**

object AllocOneTest {

    def allocProcessTest(row: Row): Unit =  {
        println("---------------- AllocOneTest::allocProcessTest::START ---------------- ")

        accum1.add(RegRptPilotConstants.PairProcessCaseClass(row(0).asInstanceOf[String], row(1).asInstanceOf[String], row(2).asInstanceOf[String]))


        println("---------------- AllocationOneTest::allocProcessTest::END ---------------- ")

    }
}

**CLASS D::**

object RegRptPilotConstants {
    var pairedOneSeq = Seq[PairProcessCaseClass]()
    val accum1 = new ProcessAccumulator[ProcessCaseClass]()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above code, foreach is the action that triggers the Spark DAG to execute the entire flow. Action, i.e foreach in the above scenario is executed/invoked on each of the partitions simultaneously in parallel thus, invoking the methods that are inside the foreach at last.

Flow: Method A --> Method B --> Method C, Method C, Method C ...

```
df.coalesce(1).sort($"PRIORITY" asc).foreach( {
    row => AllocOneTest.allocProcessTest(row)
})
```

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions

Comment: Thanks hagarwal for your reply. I am doing the below to make the methods run in order... which works but is so slow on cluster.

df.coalesce(1).sort($"PRIORITY" asc).collect().foreach( {
 row => AllocOneTest.allocProcessTest(row)
}
)

Was wondering how to process a dataset row-by-row and store results in a common collection across the cluster. Each Security group can be processed independently of others, but results from each Security Group processing have to go to a common collection.